# MS Excel eval() like function

Tags: excel-2007

I am trying to find the best moving average and stumbled upon a problem.

I can create cells with content like `B233:B253` based on a n. However, I am unable to paste this value to the `AVG()` function, which sees the value as a string.

Is there any kind of `eval()` function?

VBA is out of the game as I am going to use MS Solver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is a type of eval function - `INDIRECT`

Example
put 3 values in column A
put A1:A3 in B1
`=AVERAGE(INDIRECT(B1))` will give you the average of cells A1:A3